# write a program that reads the content of hoilday.txt, one line at a time

Tags: python-3.5

I have to do this Coding Challenge on `python 3.5.2`.

So far here is my code:

```
file = open("holiday text",'r')
contents = file.read
print(contents)
file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. Note that if the text file isn't in the same folder as the python (eg C:/Python35-32) you should specify the whole path, except if it's for some online challenge where you just provide the text file.

```
file = open("holiday text.txt",'r')
contents = file.read()
file.close()
print(contents)
```

Another way is to use the `with` statement which automatically opens/closes the file appropriately, like so:

```
with open("holiday text.txt",'r') as file:
    contents = file.read()
print(contents)
```

If it helped, please press the arrow button for accepted answer.